# How to programmatically create Traffic manager profile and auto add the traffic manager DNS name to custom domain of app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I want to create a traffic manager points to several app service cross regions. I saw that if I create the TM profile and added endpoints on Azure portal, the TM DNS name will be automatically added into the custom domain of app service.
But if I create the TM and adding endpoints using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent` library, the TM DNS name won't be added to app service custom domains. 
What is the best way to auto add the TM DNS name to app service custom domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traffic Manager DNS name cant be added to the web app. you can add custom dns name to the web app, which you can use for the traffic manager as well (as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name) article). So you'd need to do this on the webapps and point your dns record to the TM.

Comment: Thanks. Any .net library I can use to add dns name to web app?

Comment: I think you'd need official [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.hostnamesslbinding.definition?view=azure-dotnet) to do that.